# Get Emacs to jump to the start of a word after isearch

Tags: isearch, words

If I use isearch to search for the word "accommodating" in my document, I have to type acc before the cursor jumps to the word. When I press enter the cursor is on the the second "c" as in acCommodating. This strikes me as rather unintuitive because I have to go back two characters to begin editing the word. In Vim, search puts the cursor at the start of the word. Can I replicate this behaviour in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing to replicate, I think.  You somehow have to tell Isearch that you're done typing text for the search string - you have to hit *some* key to tell it that. So at a minimum you have `C-s acc <SOME KEY>`.

You can end Isearch with any key that is not already bound to something in `isearch-mode-map`. (And even then, you can rebind any keys that are already bound.) And the key that ends Isearch can do whatever you like, including move back to a word beginning.

So you can end it with `M-b` (that key isn't bound for Isearch, by default), which goes back to the beginning of the current word:

`C-s acc M-b`

That's not so hard. Whether you find it "intuitive" probably has to do with what you're already used to. There are a zillion use cases for Isearch, only one of which is wanting to move to the beginning of a matching word.

`C-h k M-b` tells you:

> `M-b` runs the command `backward-word` (found in `global-map`), which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to `M-b`, `ESC left`.
>
> `(backward-word &optional ARG)`
>
> Move backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
>
> With argument `ARG`, do this that many times.
>   If `ARG` is omitted or `nil`, move point backward one word.
>
> The word boundaries are normally determined by the buffer’s
>   syntax table and character script (according to
>   `char-script-table`), but `find-word-boundary-function-table`,
>   such as set up by `subword-mode`, can change that.  If a Lisp
>   program needs to move by words determined strictly by the syntax
>   table, it should use `backward-word-strictly` instead.  See Info
>   node [(elisp) Word Motion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Word-Motion.html) for details.

Comment: `M-b` is not very useful here if search term is not in the beginning of the word. In such cases `C-r` will help: `C-s acc C-r <RET>`.

Comment: @muffinmad: You seem to be saying that if the search string matches, say, the middle of a word, then point should be returned to the match beginning, not the word beginning. That would do what dangom's answer does. But that's not what was requested. Maybe the OP prefers that, dunno, the request was to put point at the word beginning.

Comment: I must say that I did find this answer very useful. It helped me to think about quitting isearch differently than I had before.

Comment: (OP) FYI: The answer you accepted does not answer the question that you posed. You said you wanted to go back to the beginning of the *word* that Isearch ended at. The answer you accepted goes back to the beginning of the search-string match. That coincides with the beginning of the word only if your search string matches also the beginning of the word. If it matches in the middle of the word, that answer doesn't take you to the word beginning.

Comment: You are correct. I failed to see that previously.

Comment: Someone want to explain their downvote today? I'm curious as to how the question isn't helpful.

Comment: Someone want to explain their downvote today? I'm curious as to how the question isn't helpful.

Answer (score 5):

As Drew pointed out in [his answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52550/366) you can also end the search with another key such as `M-b` or `M-f`, which for words boundaries works good, but my solution is kind of more general: define a key to put the cursor at the beginning (or end) of the pattern I'm searching:

```
(use-package isearch
  :bind (:map isearch-mode-map
              ("C-<return>" . isearch-done-opposite))
  :init (defun isearch-done-opposite (&optional nopush edit)
          "End current search in the opposite side of the match."
          (interactive)
          (funcall #'isearch-done nopush edit)
          (when isearch-other-end (goto-char isearch-other-end))))
```

**UPDATE**: or in case you don't use `use-package`:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>")
  (defun isearch-done-opposite (&optional nopush edit)
    "End current search in the opposite side of the match."
    (interactive)
    (funcall #'isearch-done nopush edit)
    (when isearch-other-end (goto-char isearch-other-end))))
```

Basically, map `C-Ret` to another function `isearch-done-opposite` which checks the variable `isearch-other-end` which is defined in `isearch.el` as:

```
(defvar isearch-other-end nil)  ; Start (end) of match if forward (backward).
```

This will work with forward and backward searches.

Comment: Is there some purpose to using `use-package` for a loaded-by-default library?  I don't see any reason to introduce the dependency... a works-for-everyone answer would seem better.

Comment: No there's not, that's just how I have it in my config.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily this has been studied by Malabarba and [published in his blog](https://endlessparentheses.com/leave-the-cursor-at-start-of-match-after-isearch.html), Endless. I have the following in my config:

```lisp
(use-package isearch
  :no-require t
  :demand t
  ;; Go to the start of current isearch match. (adapted from Endless)
  :hook (isearch-mode-end . (lambda ()
                              (when (and isearch-forward
                                         (number-or-marker-p isearch-other-end)
                                         (not mark-active)
                                         (not isearch-mode-end-hook-quit))
                                (goto-char isearch-other-end)))))
```

Check the blog entry for other solutions as well.